When using npm install, get `is not in this registry` on dependency which was unpublished and then re-published with same version
On my company's Nexus there was a dependency with version xyz, I had previously installed this version on my computer.
Today that specific version was deleted and then re-published with same xyz version, so everything is the same, except the URL of this dependency on the Nexus. It was nexus.company.com/repository/.../123 and now is nexus.company.com/repository/.../789.
I know what was done isn't correct, they should just have published a new version and be done with it, but I can't do anything about it.
Problem is when I try to install that xyz version on my computer, for some reason npm will still try to get the URL that ends in 123, instead of the new one that ends in 789. The following error is shown whenever I run npm install:
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://nexus.company.com/repository/.../-/...123
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@problem/package@http://nexus.company.com/repository/.../-/...123' is not in this registry.

I have tried the following:

npm cache verify
npm cache clean --force (I know it shouldn't be needed, but still tried)
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
npm update
Deleted node-modules
Deleted package-lock.json

This isn't a matter of setting the registry, it is correct
My question is where does npm stores that URL for later use? That URL did work before but now shouldn't be used again. Or could Nexus be returning the wrong URL to npm? I have checked and there isn't anything duplicated on Nexus and the xyz version only has that new correct URL on it.
I'm running macOS Ventura on Intel CPU.
